# Large data tables on MPDF - Can i avoid resize?

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm generating some reports on my admin and I'm exporting to PDF using the [MPDF library](https://mpdf.github.io/). But when this has a very large amount of data, MPDF is resizing the table to fit on page, so that it becomes awkward.

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? The code I am using to generate is the below. I've tried to set "shrink_tables_to_fit" to 0 and 1, both unsuccessful. Also tried to set autosize=1 to every table.

```
$stylesheet = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/site/css/layout/pdf.css');
$bootstrap = file_get_contents('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

$mpdf = new mPDF('pt', 'a4');

$mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit = 1;
$mpdf->setAutoTopMargin = 'stretch';
$mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch';

$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<img src="'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/site/img/content/pdf/header.jpg">');
$mpdf->SetFooter('{DATE j/m/Y H:i}|{PAGENO}/{nb}');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($bootstrap, 1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload/consultas-pre/'.$nomeArquivo.'.pdf', 'F');
```

Comment: Break your HTML `<table>` into multiple `<tbody>` blocks?

Comment: I believe you can try to generate a simple pdf first with just tables html. For e.g $mpdf = new mPDF('pt', 'a4'); $mpdf->WriteHTML($html); $mpdf->Output('..'); If there are any issues then you might know it is the table issue. If not you can slowly introduce other options and see what is breaking it.

Comment: @KamalSoni i guess what is breaking it is the many rows on that. With less rows, works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it.

I can not have a table with other tables inside. When this happens, MPDF gets lost in resize.

Answer (score 3):

You can split the entire table into different tables and at end of the each table add :

```
<div style="page-break-after: always;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Which will create a page break.

Example :

```
<?php $rows=1; foreach($allData as $data){ ?>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Your table data</td>
      </tr>
    </table> 

    <?php if($row == 10) { ?>
        <div style="page-break-after: always;">&nbsp;</div>
    <?php } ?>

<?php } ?>
```

You can read more about mpdf page break [here](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-breaks.html)

Comment: Interesting... i didnt know about page-breaks on mpdf. But, the problem was due to a table inside another. Removing one of them, the PDF was rendered correctly! The bounty is yours! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Tried everything I found on stackoverflow in different combinations: `shrink_tables_to_fit`, `autosize="0"`, `page-break-inside:...`, `overflow:...`, etc...

In my case my table was inside the `div` that had `position:absolute` in its inline style. After I changed it to relative or removed position completely, the table is divided properly between pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the table opening tag:

```
<table autosize="1">
```